# SQL Grouped Results with Counts and Cumulative Counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, sum

I have the following data in my 'user' table:

```
user_id | create_timestamp
1         2017-08-01
2         2017-08-01
3         2017-08-02
4         2017-08-03
5         2017-08-03
6         2017-08-03
7         2017-08-04
8         2017-08-04
9         2017-08-04
10        2017-08-04
```

I want to create a SQL query that has three columns: 
1. Grouped results by create_timestamp
2. A count of the results by date
3. A cumulative count as the date goes on.

Here's what the result set should look like:

```
create_timestamp daily cumulative
2017-08-01         2      2
2017-08-02         1      3
2017-08-03         3      6
2017-08-04         4      10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query.

```
DECLARE @UserLog TABLE (user_id INT , create_timestamp DATE)
INSERT INTO @UserLog
VALUES
(1,'2017-08-01'),
(2,'2017-08-01'),
(3,'2017-08-02'),
(4,'2017-08-03'),
(5,'2017-08-03'),
(6,'2017-08-03'),
(7,'2017-08-04'),
(8,'2017-08-04'),
(9,'2017-08-04'),
(10,'2017-08-04')

;WITH T AS (
    SELECT create_timestamp, COUNT(*) daily  FROM @UserLog
    GROUP BY create_timestamp)
    SELECT 
        create_timestamp, 
        daily, 
        SUM(daily) OVER( ORDER BY create_timestamp ASC  
                            ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) cumulative  
FROM T
```

Result

```
create_timestamp daily       cumulative
---------------- ----------- -----------
2017-08-01       2           2
2017-08-02       1           3
2017-08-03       3           6
2017-08-04       4           10
```

Comment: Also a great solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You would use window functions for this:

```
select create_timestamp, count(*) as cnt,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by create_timestamp) as cumulative
from t
group by create_timestamp
order by create_timestamp;
```

This functionality is available in SQL Server 2012+.

Note:  You may need to extract the date from the time stamp:

```
select convert(date, create_timestamp) as dte, count(*) as cnt,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by convert(date, create_timestamp)) as cumulative
from t
group by convert(date, create_timestamp)
order by convert(date, create_timestamp);
```

Comment: This is not quite working.  It's giving me more than double the rows, it has 1 as the value in the cnt for every value, but the cumulative might be working as expected.